# Counting Elements in Multiple Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

How to build a table that counts how many times **each** element in mainlist occurs in lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4 and which lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4 contains that element. For example, in mainlist, element N6073 has count = 4 and N6073 appears in lst1, lst2, lst3, and lst4. In mainlist, element N12061 has count = 2 and N12061 appears in lst1, lst3.

```
mainlist = {N6073, N6019, N12061, N6025, N6065, N6071, N6039, N6077, 
  N53023, N22103, N38077, N12093, N12111, N12035, N22117, N12053, 
  N41005, N4019, N22051, N22105}
lst1 = {N12061, N12111, N4019, N41005, N53023, N6019, N6025, N6065, 
  N6073, N6077}
lst2 = {N12053, N12093, N22117, N6019, N6025, N6039, N6073}
lst3 = {N12061, N12111, N4019, N6065, N6071, N6073}
lst4 = {N22103, N4019, N6019, N6025, N6039, N6065, N6073}
```

Comment: `Join[lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4] // Counts`

Comment: very nice and can you then identify which of the lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4 each element in the mainlist falls into?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
table = {#, Counts[Join[lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]] @ # /. _Missing -> 0, 
     Function[x, Select[{"lst1", "lst2", "lst3", "lst4"}, 
        MemberQ[x] @ ToExpression[#] &]] @ #} & /@ mainlist;

headers = {"element", "count", "lists"};

grid = Prepend[table, headers];

grid // Grid
```

[image]

Alternative approaches:

[`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html):

```
sa = SparseArray[Outer[Boole @* MemberQ,  {lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4}, mainlist, 1]];

parents = Extract[{"lst1", "lst2", "lst3", "lst4"}, 
   List /@ Transpose[sa]["AdjacencyLists"]];

table2 = Transpose[{mainlist, Total[sa, 1], parents}];
table2 == table
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

[`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html):

```
rg = RelationGraph[MemberQ[ToExpression@#2, #] &, 
  mainlist, {"lst1", "lst2", "lst3", "lst4"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
table3 = {#, VertexDegree[rg, #], AdjacencyList[rg, #]} & /@ mainlist;
table3 == table
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Comment: super clever ... awesome kglr and many thank you's ... prg

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["`*"];
mainlist = {N6073, N6019, N12061, N6025, N6065, N6071, N6039, N6077, 
   N53023, N22103, N38077, N12093, N12111, N12035, N22117, N12053, 
   N41005, N4019, N22051, N22105};
lst1 = {N12061, N12111, N4019, N41005, N53023, N6019, N6025, N6065, 
   N6073, N6077};
lst2 = {N12053, N12093, N22117, N6019, N6025, N6039, N6073};
lst3 = {N12061, N12111, N4019, N6065, N6071, N6073};
lst4 = {N22103, N4019, N6019, N6025, N6039, N6065, N6073};
Subtract[#, 1] & /@ Counts[Join[mainlist, lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]]
```

The result is

```
<|N6073 -> 4, N6019 -> 3, N12061 -> 2, N6025 -> 3, N6065 -> 3, 
 N6071 -> 1, N6039 -> 2, N6077 -> 1, N53023 -> 1, N22103 -> 1, 
 N38077 -> 0, N12093 -> 1, N12111 -> 2, N12035 -> 0, N22117 -> 1, 
 N12053 -> 1, N41005 -> 1, N4019 -> 3, N22051 -> 0, N22105 -> 0|>
```